# Why I see the outputs of export file in imported file console Javascript?

Tags: javascript, import, console, export, console.log

Is it normal, when I export a variable from javascript code to another, I can see the console outputs of this file that I used export statement? Here is HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="/first.js" type="module"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my first.js:

```
import { a } from "./second.js";
console.log(a);
```

Here is second.js:

```
export let a = "Hello";
console.log("A try...");
```

When I run first.html, I expected to see console like:
Hello

But I got this:

A try...
Hello

Is it normal and is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: `console.log(a);` will `log` to the `console` ... why does this surprise you? to prevent logging things to the console, do not use `console.log` ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: The log inside second will run before first.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the issue is here.  You have a `console.log` statement, which is logging to the console.  To prevent it... remove that statement?

Comment: Actually the question might not be a silly as it sounds,  Yes, `second.js` has side effects, been the `console.log`, but in theory dead code elimination with side effects not active, could in theory exclude that `console.log`, maybe this is what the OP is getting at..

Comment: I mean I did not run second.js, I did first.js. console.log("A try...") is not in first.js, it is included to second.js but I see when I run first.js

Comment: @Carasidelt  That's how modules are loaded, without dead code elimination / tree shaking, the module is loaded and executed.  eg. with webpack you could mark `second.js` as been side effect free, and that `console.log` would not happen during build / tree shaking..  eg. -> https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#mark-the-file-as-side-effect-free   But to be fair I would avoid doing this, it's much simpler if you don't do any side effects in your module, if you don't want them executing.

Comment: Also worth pointing out module side-effects are very useful, if you import `second.js` again from another module you will notice it will  not `console.log` again,  IOW: a modules side effects are only run once, this is very handy say for initialising things, like database etc, so you certainly would not want to disable them totally.

Comment: @Keith thank u so much you are the only one that  understands me.